# What is the sum of the elements in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science

I was trying to figure out the time complexity of creating the prefix table in KMP algorithm.
Basically i want to know the maximum value possible of the sum of absolute values of the terms in a sequence of n elements.
The sequence is very simple - 
 The ith term in the sequence (i ranges from 1 to n) can be 0,1 or -x. 
Where x is less than or equal to the sum of all elements Aj from j=1 to j=i-1.
Examples : 
S1 -> 0 0 0 1 1 -2 
S2 ->0 0 1 1 -2 0 1 -1
S3 -> 0 1 -1.
Let us assume that the sum of absolute values of the sum = ANS.
For the above sequences the values of ANS for s1,s2,s3 respectively are 4,6 and 2. 
I want the know the tightest upper bound on the value of ANS for a given sequence in terms of n. Like the big O notations. For large values of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any finite sequence of $n$-legal moves $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$. Let $a_k$ be the partial sums:

$$a_k = \sum_{i=1}^k u_i \quad\text{ for }\quad k = 1, \ldots n$$

The second condition of $u_i$ tell us $a_k \ge 0$ for all $k$.

Let $m_0$, $m_1$ be the number of zeros and ones among $u_k$. Let $A$ be the sum of absolute values of negative $u_i$:

$$A \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{i=1, u_i < 0}^n |u_i|$$

In terms of $m_0, m_1, A$, the the sum of absolute values of all $u_k$ is simply

$$S \stackrel{def}{=} \sum_{i=1}^n |u_i| = m_1 + A$$

Notice

$$a_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n u_i = m_1 - A
\quad\implies\quad S = 2m_1 - a_n$$

When $m_0 + m_1 = n$ (ie. there is no negative $u_i$), we have
$$a_n  = m_1\quad\implies\quad S = 2m_1 - m_1 = m_1 \le n$$

When $m_0 + m_1 < n$, then using the fact $a_n \ge 0$, we have
$$S = 2m_1 - a_n \le 2m_1 \le 2(n-1)$$

Combine these two cases, we obtain an upper bound

$$S \le 2(n-1)$$
Since this upper bound is attainable by the moves
$$(u_1,\ldots, u_n) = (1,1,1\dots,1,-(n-1))$$
This upper bound is tight.

Comment: Nice Explanation. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal strategy is to choose all elements to be $1$ and the last element to be minus the sum of the previous ones. That way for a sequence of length $n$ the sum of the absoulte values of the sequence is $2(n-1)$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c} n & a & \Sigma \\ \hline 2 & 1,-1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1,1,-2 & 4 \\ 4 & 1,1,1,-3 & 6 \\ 5 & 1,1,1,1,-4 & 8 \end{array}$$